# PIL Polygons with holes

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a shape file, which have holes, eg. a lake with islands. If no other data is present, I could just draw the inner polygon with the color that was present before. but if something was drawn in that area before, that data is lost. so, as i see it, there are 2 possible solutions:

1: If I can, i would prefer to just NOT draw in that area

2: if necessary, i guess its possible to get the pixel data of the inner polygon, and redraw     that, when the outer polygon has been drawn.

So, to summarize, need help with ether a way to draw holes in PIL, or how to get the image data from a specified polygon of a image.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't draw the outline of the ploygon or draw it in the same color as the interior is filled, you could do them as [weakly simple polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon#Weakly_simple_polygon).

Comment: Thanks for that idea. Actualy i do need to color the border, but that can just be done later, using

Comment: Any update for the solution.. My use case is also similar. Need to keep blank empty area for holes and rest other need to fill with colour,

Comment: I must admit i don't remember what i ended up doing 8 years ago haha :) I suppose i followed the suggestion by @martineau